# Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/util/ArrayMap;

Tags: android, gradle, support-v4

for some reason my app dosent work on devices with api 21&&22 in relsase mode (in debug mode everything is fine)
the app crash right away after start in the console i am getting this error

```
ava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/util/ArrayMap;
                                                       at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
                                                       at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                       at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1714)
                                                       at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1683)
```

the app the latest versions of firebase 11.8.0 and of google services 11.8.0 and of support libary 27.0.2
there is no missing dependency ("com.android.support:support-v4") is included

Comment: Did you find a fix for this?

Comment: @Ido Kahana How did you fix this issues please post you answer